# Powershell replace year regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am trying to replace all the file names in the folder that have the year different than 2021.

Example:

```
some_random_text_20240102 --> some_random_text_20210102 
some_random_text_20220320 --> some_random_text_20210102 
some_random_text_20241020 --> some_random_text_20210102
```

The only digits are at the end of the file's name. The year represents the first 4. I can't figure out how to add this to the logic (haven't done regex before)

Get-ChildItem -Path "." -Filter "*.csv" | Rename-Item -NewName { $*.BaseName.Replace("20[0-9][0-9]","2021") + $*.Extension }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\" -Filter "*.csv" | `
   Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=_)(?!2021)\d{4}(?=\d{4}\.csv$)', '2021' }
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xqTKRd/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=_)`  - a location that is immediately preceded with a `_` char
- `(?!2021)` - the next four chars on the right cannot be a `2021` string
- `\d{4}` - any four digits
- `(?=\d{4}\.csv$)` - immediately after the four digits, there must be another four digits, and then `.csv` that should be at the end of string.